# как определить что маркер(Point) находится внутри Полигона?

Tags: flutter, dart

использую библиотеку `yandex_mapkit`, есть ли формула при котором если маркер отмечен в зоне полигона возвращает `true`, а иначе `false`?

т.е:
если `Point` внутри `List<Polygon>` то `true`, а если `Point` снаружи `List<Polygon>` то `false`.

Использую эту формулу но что то она возвращает не точно:

```
bool isOnlinePayment(Point point, List<Polygon> polygons) {
    bool inside = false;
    var x = point.latitude, y = point.longitude;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < polygons.length; ii++) {
      var polyPoints = polygons[ii].coordinates;
      for (int i = 0, j = polyPoints.length - 1; i < polyPoints.length; i++) {
        var xi = polyPoints[i].latitude, yi = polyPoints[i].longitude;
        var xj = polyPoints[j].latitude, yj = polyPoints[j].longitude;
        var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y)) &&
            (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
        if (intersect) inside = !inside;
      }
    }
    return inside;
  }
```

Comment: У вас какая точность latitude и longitude? И ссылку на формулу можно?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790344/determine-if-a-point-reside-inside-a-leaflet-polygon